# Windows key when running windows through virtual box on a mac

Tags: windows, virtualbox

I am running Windows 7 on a virtual image using virtualbox on my max osx.
I need to know what the windows key is on the mac keyboard.  Any tips?

Answer (score 43):

By default it's the **right** <kbd>⌘ (Command)</kbd> Key.

The left <kbd>⌘ (Command)</kbd> Key does not work because it is set as the **Host (Meta) Key** in VirtualBox.

And they can be swapped simply by replacing the **Host Key** with the **right** <kbd>⌘ (Command)</kbd> Key, in Preferences > Input > Virtual Machine > **Host Key Combination**.

Comment: awesome! that's what I am look for.

Comment: Brilliantly stupid that I didn't do this without your help Mate Mike! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

On Virtualbox 4.3.6, I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> for the <kbd>Windows</kbd> button.

Tested on Windows 7 and 8.1

Comment: I can't downvote on this site, but this answer is wrong. Ctrl+Esc is a default hotkey to open start menu on Windows, regardless of it being on a VM or real hardware. Ctrl+Esc doesn't work as Windows key in any application, and none of keyboard shortcuts utilising the Windows key will work with Ctrl+Esc.

Comment: @AlexanderRevo the <kbd>Windows</kbd> open the start menu, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> also open the start menu. It is what expected.

Comment: Opening start menu is not the only thing that Windows key does. There are plenty of hot keys utilising the Windows key, none of which can be used with Ctrl+Esc. Just because Ctrl+Esc performs one of Windows key’s functions doesn’t mean it’s equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

In **2021**, if you're using a Mac and want the left <kbd>⌘</kbd> on the Mac to act as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows in "Windows VM", you can do as following:

**1. Change default Meta-key in VirtualBox**

- On the Mac, focus on a running "Windows VM"
- Select: **Input** menu > **Keyboard** > **Keyboard Settings...**
- Look at **Input** tab > **Virtual Machine**
- Under **Host key Combination**, change the left <kbd>⌘</kbd> to the right <kbd>⌘</kbd> by clicking on the field, press the right <kbd>⌘</kbd>

=> Now your Meta-key is the right <kbd>⌘</kbd>

=> The "Windows" key on Windows will be assigned back to the left <kbd>⌘</kbd>

=> Stop here if that was all you need.

**2. Switch function of "Windows" key (left <kbd>⌘</kbd>) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key to each other in "Windows VM"**

- In "Windows VM", install Microsoft's PowerToys from this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install)
- Open the program after finishing the setup process
- Select **Keyboard Manager** menu item on the left, and then click on **Remap a key** on the right
- Click on **Type** button under **Key** column, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
- Click on **Type** button under **Mapped To** column, and press left <kbd>⌘</kbd>
- Then, you need to do the same but in reverse order

  - Click on **Type** button under **Key** column, and type left <kbd>⌘</kbd>
  - Click on **Type** button under **Mapped To** column, and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

=> The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> (Mac) is now the "Windows" key ("Windows VM")

=> And the left <kbd>⌘</kbd> (Mac) is now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> ("Windows VM")

Comment: Would you mind if I edited this so the [key caps matched actual keys](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/210/5472)? Superb answer!

Comment: @bmike Please go ahead if the change would make it looks better.

Comment: Will do later and remove the comments. You can edit further if you don’t like the change as well or revert

Answer (score 1):

By default the Windows key is mapped to the Command key on an Apple keyboard.

On the Windows 7 Desktop, tap the Command key and see if the Start menu appears.

You can change the mapping of keys in VirtualBox if you don't like the default mapping as well.