# Command key when running Mac through virtual box on Windows OS

Tags: macos, keyboard, password, virtualbox

I just recently installed Yosemite in Virtualbox. Here's the installation video I followed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYMEb0ZCfes

My OS is Windows and I'm trying to run Mac using Virtualbox.

I had no problems with booting and stuff. After booting, Mac installation settings appeared, then the system asked me to set log in details (full name, username, password). However, while I am retyping my desired password, the screen suddenly turned black. I waited and did nothing. The next thing it showed was the start up screen where it asks for my username and password.

I tried entering my username and password, but it won't work. I knew I haven't completed setting my log-in details due to the screen turning black. I searched for possible solutions, one thing I'd like to try is to use Recovery Mode and reset the password (http://www.macworld.com/article/2868032/what-to-do-if-your-mac-refuses-to-accept-your-password.html).

However though, can't figure out how to key 'Command-R'. Does anyone know how?

Also, it would be great if someone could suggest other things that might work if ever pw reset through Recovery Mode fails. I'd appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 4):

I would much rather point to this previous question/answer in a comment but my rep does not allow comments.

There are 3 answers: [Windows key when running windows through virtual box on a mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/97168/windows-key-when-running-windows-through-virtual-box-on-a-mac)

By default it's the right ⌘ (Command) Key.

The left ⌘ (Command) Key does not work because it is set as the Host (Meta) Key in VirtualBox.

And they can be swapped simply by replacing the Host Key with the right ⌘ (Command) Key, in Preferences > Input > Virtual Machine > Host Key Combination.

Comment: I used this procedure to switch the host key, but there's still a problem. If I type a Command key that's one of VirtualBox's shortcuts, it's captured by VirtualBox instead of being sent to the guest. E.g. Cmd-Q asks if I want to kill the VM, rather than exiting the application I'm running in the VM. Is there any way around this other than changing all the shortcuts?

Comment: You were asked opposite